# Upload a .zip file to FTP and unzip it using PHP

Tags: php, upload, ftp, zip, unzip

I'm trying to make a script that would upload a certain zip file , currently "test.zip", and then unzip it. I found some answers in this website about how to unzip but got no idea how to do it on an FTP server. All using PHP Please.

Current code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('test.zip');
$zip->extractTo('./');
$zip->close();
```

Thanks again :)

Comment: That looks like it would do the unzipping. Are you wanting to programmatically FTP it as well? Before or after the unzipping? To or from the server that is unzipping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before unzipping it you can upload the zip by using a form (make your own admin area?/localhost only?). I copied this from my code for uploading images and will only upload .zip files
HTML part:

```
<form action='file.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>
    <p>Please Upload a ZIP File.</p>
    <input type='file' name='file'>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

PHP part:

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"])[1]; //Get the extension
if($temp == "zip"){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"unzipme.zip") or die("Couldn't upload. Check permissions and retry.");
            //Relocate home?
    header("Location: /");
    exit();
}
```

You need permissions to upload to your directories, www-date or something similar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually I meant the www-data group*

Answer (score 1):

First you should upload the zip archive to the server.
Here is an example of how to do basic FTP things in PHP.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ftp.examples-basic.php

After that you should be able to unzip the file on the server using the method you described in the question.

Comment: Sry I forgot to mention it , I already created a script that uploads the ZIP, only need to unzip it on the machine, I don't know how to configure this method to work with the FTP session.

Comment: @Beater I don't see why you need to configure things. If the zip-file is on the machine, and you know its filename, you can just unzip it, right?

Answer (score 1):

You either need access to execute commands or programs on the machine you are uploading to, or the ability to also upload a script that you can execute via a URL. If you are uploading via FTP to a web server directory that can run PHP, then upload your zip archive and the unzip.php file there and load the unzip.php page in your browser.

Comment: Don't have any kind of that access, This is made for other people to upload like PhpBB files to their FTP directory.. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: Unfortunately, unzipping is a command that needs to run on the machine where the unzipping occurs. If you don't have SSH or telnet access, and if the FTP account does not include a web-accessible folder, you won't be able to unzip it once it is up.  You can, though, create a manifest file describing everything in the zip archive and send it along if that is all you need.  I actually don't understand why you'd need them unzipped if it isn't a web-accessible location.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for Extract folder in your FTP, create a new Php file copy below code and run it:

```
$path = getcwd();

$zip = new ZipArchive;

$res = $zip->open('yourZippedFolder.zip');

if ($res === TRUE) {

  $zip->extractTo($path.'/maunil/');

  $zip->close();

  echo 'Successfully Extracted';

}

else 
{

 echo 'failed to Extract';

}
```